# How to enable on click after removing it?

Tags: javascript

I have two conditions here, cond1 and cond2 .If its the cond1 I will disable my `onclick` event, else I will enable it.

This is what I fished out :

```
if(cond1) {
    document.getElementById('mTag').removeAttribute("onclick");
} else {
    document.getElementById('mTag').setAttribute('onclick');
}
```

The problem is once the `onclick` gets disabled , its not getting enabled again. If its `cond2` , then it must be enabled . What am I doing wrong? Kindly suggest some solution to this.

Comment: If you read the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.setAttribute) carefully, you might notice that `setAttribute` must also have `value` argument.

Comment: For, setAttribute, shouldn't the second parameter be the name of your onclick function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why would you do that? This will be annoying user experience anyway. Better is to disable/enable the tag:

```
document.getElementById('mTag').disabled = cond1;
```

To prevent the click event, you have to [prevent the event from bubbling upwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4725242/disable-onclick-event).

```
document.getElementById('mTag').onclick = function(e) {
    if (!e) var e = window.event;
    event.cancelBubble = !cond1;

    ...
};
```

Comment: This would still trigger the click handler, I'd say. So the next step would be to check the `disabled` status in the click handler (see answer @Raffaele), right?

Answer (score 1):

You did it wrong. Removing the attribute doesn't unbind the event.
This is the right way:

```
document.getElementById("mTag").onclick = null;
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need to remove onclick attribute you can set a flag in your handler

```
var enable;
function myhandler() {
    if (enable) {
        //my code
    }
}

if(cond1){
   enable = false;
} else {
   enabled = true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it's better to set a flag, and check for that flag at the beginning of your handler:

```
function handler(event) {
  if ( !this.flag )
    return;
  // do the actual handling
}
```